# Spring ConditionalGenericConverter based on source object's instance variable value

Tags: java, spring, type-conversion

I have a class Request.class which I would like to convert it to Response.class based on a condition : if the instance of Request.class has a boolean instance variable isValid set to true, if not this Converter should not be triggered. Is there a way we can implement this using ConditionalGenericConverter interface which Spring provides? or are there any better approaches to this problem?

```
public class RequestToResponseConverter implements ConditionalGenericConverter {
    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        Set<ConditionalGenericConverter.ConvertiblePair> pairs = new LinkedHashSet<>(); 
          pairs.add(new ConditionalGenericConverter.ConvertiblePair(Request.class, Response.class)); 
          return pairs;

    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(//request.isValid){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: How are you going to decide if the object instance `source` has `isValid` field set to true without invoking the conversion class's `convert` method? Just calling `matches` method has no way to know the state of the object `convert` method receives. So why would you want to avoid calling conversion class altogether. Does it make sense to still call the converter class and return `null` in case `isValid` is set to false

Comment: Hi my requirement is based on isValid flag if its set to false i need to call a different converter